# Printing images of each clusters

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I used the sklearn KMeans for forming the images clusters, I am facing difficulty in printing the images of each clusters.

1. I have a np array train of dimension: (10000, 100, 100, 3)
2. Then I flatten the image so each row present a image. Train dimension:(10000, 30000)
3. I applied the KMeans.

   ```
   from scipy import ndimage

   from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

   kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=10, random_state=0)

   clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(train)

   centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
   ```

After this I want to print the images of each clusters,

Comment: Have you tried print(centers) ?

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/k-means-clustering-with-scikit-learn/ refer this

Comment: @NikolasRieble centers shape is (10, 100, 100, 3) so I am getting only 10 images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ten clusters, you will get ten cluster centers. You can now print them or you can visualize them - which is what I assume you would like to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#fake centers 
centers = np.random.random((10,100,100,3))

#print centers
for ci in centers:
    print(ci)

#visualize centers:
for ci in centers: 
    plt.imshow(ci)
    plt.show()
```

EDIT: I understand that you not only wish to visualize centers, but other members from each cluster.

You could do it as follows for a single random member:

```
from scipy import ndimage
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#PARAMS
n_clusters=10  

#fake train data
original_train = np.random.random((100, 100, 100, 3)) #100 images of each 100 px,py and RGB 

n,x,y,c = original_train.shape

flat_train = original_train.reshape((n,x*y*c))

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters, random_state=0)

clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(flat_train)

centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

#visualize centers:
for ci in centers: 
    plt.imshow(ci.reshape(x,y,c))
    plt.show()

#visualize other members
for cluster in np.arange(n_clusters):

    cluster_member_indices = np.where(clusters == cluster)[0]
    print("There are %s members in cluster %s" % (len(cluster_member_indices), cluster))

    #pick a random member
    random_member = random.choice(cluster_member_indices)
    plt.imshow(original_train[random_member,:,:,:])
    plt.show()
```

Comment: but it's showing only 10 images, how to show some images from each centres

Comment: It seems there is some misunderstanding about what a cluster and a center means. You used KMeans to cluster your data with 10 clusters. Then you want to visualize/print the centers of your clusters. For each cluster there exists one center. Then you will have 10 cluster centers.

Comment: You are absolutely right in your argument, but OP arguably asks how to print *some* images (i.e. a sample) from each cluster, and not the cluster centers; and in any case, I am not sure how meaningful/interesting it is to print the cluster centers in such a case.

Comment: I edited the answer accordingly which now plot a random member. With little adjustments he instead plot all members, plot N members, etc.